# RxJS Subjects and Angular 2 components

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am coming to terms with the fact that web development is changing and I need to get to grips with RxJS. I am currently developing a web app using Angular 2.0.0-beta.15.

I am following the most excellent [ng-book 2](https://www.ng-book.com/2/) (is that kind of advertising allowed? Oh well). It covers in broad, shallow strokes some important concepts in RxJS and provides links to further reading. I have read and understood the source code and accompanying explanation, but am left a little in the dark about some details regarding `Subject`s in particular and how Angular 2 components consume these Subject streams.

I have augmented the code from the book thusly:

```
export class SubmitResourceComponent {
    private _newResourceTags: Subject<Tag> = new Subject<Tag>();
    private _resourceTags: Observable<Tag[]>;
    private _tagUpdates: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
    private _create: Subject<Tag> = new Subject<Tag>();
    private _remove: Subject<Tag> = new Subject<Tag>();

    constructor() {
        this._resourceTags = this._tagUpdates
            .scan((tags: Tag[], operation: ITagsOperation) => operation(tags), initialTags);

        this._create
            .map((tag: Tag): ITagsOperation => (tags: Tag[]) => _.uniq(tags.concat(tag)))
            .subscribe(this._tagUpdates);

        this._remove
            .map((tag: Tag): ITagsOperation => (tags: Tag[]) => _.without(tags, tag))
            .subscribe(this._tagUpdates);

        this._newResourceTags.subscribe(this._create);
    }

    get resourceTags(): Observable<Tag[]> {
        return this._resourceTags;
    } 

    protected addTagToResource(tag: Tag): void {
        this._create.next(tag);
    }

    protected removeTagFromResource(tag: Tag): void {
        this._remove.next(tag);
    }
}
```

And I am consuming the `_resourceTags` like this:

```
<button class="btn" *ngFor="#tag of resourceTags | async" (click)="removeTagFromResource(tag)">{{ tag.name }}</button>
```

What I can't grasp, even with excellent support from the gitter forums, is why the UI displays all of the tags that are pushed into the `_resourceTags` `Subject`. I would imagine that the stream is like a rubber pipe: once an element has been pushed into the `Subject` and published to whatever `Observer` (in this case, the UI element), does it not then evaporate and disappear? Does it stay in the stream/pipe/`Subject`? How is the UI element subscribing to the `Subject`? Am I thinking about it in the wrong way? Do I need a complete mental restructuring/transplant?

So many questions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Data passed to `next` is like an event. The subscriber gets the value and the `Observable` created by the `Subject` doesn't hold any reference to it (except you use special operators with the purpose to buffer or by other means keep emitted values.

With `| async` Angular subscribes to the `Observable` (`Subject`) and when it receives a value it displays it.

`*ngFor` only renders arrays. If you want use `*ngFor` with `Subject`, the subject needs to emit arrays - each event is not a single value but an array of values and these values are rendered by `*ngFor` and replaced by other values when the `Observable` emits a new array.

[**scan operator**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan)

Your code example uses the `scan` operator with the purpose to accumulate emitted values and forward an array that contains all values emitted so far each time it receives a new event like required by `*ngFor`.

Comment: Since this uses RxJS 5, you should link to the RxJS 5 docs for [`scan`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan).

Comment: "With | async Angular subscribes to the Observable (Subject) and when it receives a value it displays it." - I'm assuming that all of the tags are pushed through to the Angular component each time the "collection" is changed, by either adding or removing a tag, is that right? It must do, otherwise you couldn't delete a tag and this code is functioning correctly. I think I just need to create lots of logs to see exactly when side effects are occurring and what the collections are doing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "all of the tags are pushed through to the Angular component each time". `...scan()` emits a new event with a copy of all the collected tags and the subscribed `*ngFor` rebuilds the rendered elements based on the new received array.

Answer (score 1):

I think observables store values of a variable in the browser memory only until the session is cleared, just like how you would set up a variable to get a value from an input box and upon hitting refresh on the browser the values is emptied. In the above scenario i would think like most SPAs the browser is prevented from default behavior of refresh/reload and you get some sort of persistence so when you do an operation like

```
...  _.uniq(tags.concat(tag))).subscribe(this._tagUpdates);...
```

the values continue to pile up as they're concated by the create event but would disappear when a manual refresh on the page occurs and clear the session

**EDIT**

Maybe i got the question wrong but what i mean is this:
_resourceTags starts empty, a value is created by the create event, now ***_resourceTags*** is ***[newValue#1]*** angular detects change and rerenders _resourceTags using ngFor, after a new create event ***_resourceTags*** is now ***[newValue#1, newValue#2]*** angular rerenders showing both now. If the stream is not being persisted to an online database like firebase or offline one like websql it would mean upon reloading the browser ***_resourceTags*** will go back to being empty

Comment: Somehow this answer doesn't seem to be related to the question.

Comment: oh sorry i assumed you wanted to know how it's possible that the values dont disappear