# Angular2: how to lock methods access?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have in my code something like

```js
class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate 
async canActivate(...) {
    console.log('canActivate....1');
    const currentRole = this.settings.getCurrentRole();
    if (!currentRole)
        console.log('canActivate....2');
        currentRole=await this.service.fetchAuthRoleFromServer(url);
```

in the AuthenticationService I have something like

```js
class AuthenticationService{
   constructor(sett:settings){
     sett.initData(...);
```

and in the settings class:

```js
class settings
async initData(...){
    console.log('initData....1');
    const role = await roleService.getAuthenticated();
    console.log('initData....2');
    this.setCurrentRole(role);
    console.log('initData....3');
```

and the log-file looks finally like

```
initData....1
canActivate....1
canActivate....2
initData....2
initData....3
```

Is there a way to lock the method `this.settings.getCurrentRole()` until at least I've reached `initData....3` (within the same class [`settings`])?

I tried some investigations about Semaphores but somehow couldn't get them running (in Angular)... Either I've installed the package wrong or... But perhaps there is  a more suitable solution...

**UPDATE:**
After some research I found out that the issue is highly related with the guarded route mechanism and matter of fact is that I need to init some data while in the canActivate I need to check is already logged in. If not than either fetch the content or move to the login page. But anyway the mechanism is quite strange.

Comment: If you use Observable you cannot lock but you can wait to emit data. Please provide the code of the related service(s).

Comment: Can you include more of the code, who consumes `canActivate` and `initDate`, Are you awaiting your calls `async` calls?

Answer (score 1):

This works for Angular 2/4, [and for AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799520/rxjs-subjects-and-angular2-components)

You could add a Behavior Subject to your 'initdate' function (which could be a boolean or a number) :

```
class settings
  isInitDone = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  async initDate(...){
    console.log('initData....1');
    const role = await roleService.getAuthenticated();
    console.log('initData....2');
    this.setCurrentRole(role);
    console.log('initData....3');

    //give a new value to this subject
    this.isInitDone.next(true);
  }
```

this would require the Auth class to subscribe to changes of this subject:

```
class Auth...
async canActivate(...) {
console.log('canActivate....1');

this.settings.isInitDone.subscribe(isAvailable => {
  if (isAvailable) {
    //Do your stuff
  }
});
```